How to properly use HttpClient in .NET 4.6.1 + ASP.NET Web API 2
I am creating this article using machine translation. Please forgive any grammatical errors.
I am maintaining an ASP.NET Web API 2 that runs on .NET 4.6.1.
(Don't mention the end of support! I have been telling them to upgrade many times. Woe to my unsympathetic boss!!)
In this application, I am thinking of using HttpClient to access other web servers.
Here is the code I wrote:
namespace myApps.Controllers.WebAPI
{
    public class TempTestController : ApiController
    {
        private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        [Route("AthorSiteContent")]
        public IHttpActionResult getAthorSiteContent(string A_few_URLs)
        {
            var firstRequest = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage();
            firstRequest.Method = System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Head;
            firstRequest.RequestUri = new Uri(A_few_URLs);

            var firstResponse = httpClient.SendAsync(firstRequest).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            // check headers(host, status, Content-Type, Content-Length, etc...)
            // If the content cannot be downloaded, the process ends here.

            var secondRequest = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage();
            secondRequest.Method = System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get;
            secondRequest.RequestUri = new Uri(A_few_URLs);

            var secondResponse = httpClient.SendAsync(secondRequest).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            var contentData = secondResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            // Save contentData to a file

            return new ResponseMessageResult(this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent));
        }
    }
}

Is this code safe? Won't it lead to socket exhaustion?
In addition, I am not using HttpWebRequest because I found information that

using HttpWebRequest in ASP.NET can lead to socket exhaustion.

update:
Based on the advice I received, I modified the source code to add the following features:

Deletion of unnecessary instances & support for DNS updates
Use different HttpClient instances for each host

PS: Thanks to Neil T for letting me know that the machine translation was correct! :-)
public class TempTestController : ApiController
{
    //for multithreading
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, httpClientWrapper> httpClientDics = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, httpClientWrapper>();

    [Route("AthorSiteContent")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> getAthorSiteContent(string A_few_URLs)
    {
        //To delete unnecessary instances and deal with DNS updates.
        var httpClientDicsKeys = new List<string>(httpClientDics.Keys);
        foreach (var key in httpClientDicsKeys)
        {
            if (httpClientDics[key].lastAccess < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-60))
            {
                httpClientDics[key].Dispose();
                httpClientDics.TryRemove(key, out httpClientWrapper removeObject);
            }
        }

        //Create an instance of HttpClient required to access BaseAddress if it does not already exist.
        string baseAddress = httpClientWrapper.getBaseAddressFromURL(A_few_URLs);
        if (!httpClientDicsKeys.Contains(baseAddress))
        {
            httpClientDics.TryAdd(baseAddress, new httpClientWrapper(A_few_URLs));
        }

        {
            var firstRequest = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage();
            firstRequest.Method = System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Head;
            firstRequest.RequestUri = new Uri(A_few_URLs);
            var firstResponse = await httpClientDics[baseAddress].httpClient.SendAsync(firstRequest);

            //check headers(host, status, Content-Type, Content-Length, etc...)
            //If the content cannot be downloaded, the process ends here.
        }

        //If site cannot be accessed because DNS has been updated, lastAccess will not be changed.
        httpClientDics[baseAddress].lastAccess = DateTime.Now;

        {
            var secondRequest = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage();
            secondRequest.Method = System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get;
            secondRequest.RequestUri = new Uri(A_few_URLs);
            var secondResponse = await httpClientDics[baseAddress].httpClient.SendAsync(secondRequest);
            var contentData = await secondResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            //Save contentData to a file
        }

        return new ResponseMessageResult(this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent));
    }
}

class httpClientWrapper : IDisposable
{
    public HttpClient httpClient { get; set; }
    public DateTime lastAccess { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public httpClientWrapper(string url)
    {
        this.httpClient = new HttpClient()
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(httpClientWrapper.getBaseAddressFromURL(url))
        };
    }

    public static string getBaseAddressFromURL(string url)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(url);
        return uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
    }

    //Microsoft, this code is not COOL...
    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                this.httpClient.Dispose();
            }
            this.httpClient = null;
            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    ~httpClientWrapper()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }
    #endregion
}


If "Woe to my unsympathetic boss!!" is the result of machine translation then I would encourage its wider use.

I would await async methods rather than block them (.GetAwaiter().GetResult() is bad, await ... should be ok).

It will not lead to socket exhaustion because you are using static member for HttpClient. But it can lead to problems related to DNS changes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines

Current code can lead to socket exhaustion, why? Because for every request you're using two different HttpClientHandler but at least you can make it one to be safer.
Let's assume this is the URL requested:
https://cdn.example.com/files/today.mp4

I think better to make the code safer like this:
public class TempTestController : ApiController
    {
        //private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(); this won't help without baseAddress

        [Route("AthorSiteContent")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> getAthorSiteContent(string A_few_URLs)
        {
            // url: https://cdn.example.com/files/today.mp4
            // baseAddress: https://cdn.example.com
            var httpClient = new HttpClient()
            {
                BaseAddress= new Uri("https://cdn.example.com")
            };
            
            {
                var firstRequest = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage();
                firstRequest.Method = System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Head;
                firstRequest.RequestUri = new Uri("/files/today.mp4"); //using the same httpClientHandler
                var firstResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(firstRequest);

                //check headers(host, status, Content-Type, Content-Length, etc...)
                //If the content cannot be downloaded, the process ends here.
            }

            {
                var secondRequest = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage();
                secondRequest.Method = System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get;
                secondRequest.RequestUri = new Uri("/files/today.mp4"); //using the same httpClientHandler
                var secondResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(secondRequest);
                var contentData = await secondResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

                //Save contentData to a file
            }

            return new ResponseMessageResult(this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent));
        }
    }

If you know that the base URLs are few and can be requested frequently then this solution is better by using a dictionary to save and reusing httpclient objects.
public class TempTestController : ApiController
    {
        // by dic you can reuse httpClient objects
        private static Dictionary<string, HttpClient> httpClients = new();

        [Route("AthorSiteContent")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> getAthorSiteContent(string A_few_URLs)
        {
            // url: https://cdn.example.com/files/today.mp4
            var baseAddress= "https://cdn.example.com"
            if(!httpClients.TryGetValue(baseAddress, out var httpClient))
            {
                var httpClient = new HttpClient()
                {
                    BaseAddress= new Uri("https://cdn.example.com")
                };
                
                //add to dic
                httpClients.TryAdd(baseAddress, httpClient);
            }
            
            {
                var firstRequest = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage();
                firstRequest.Method = System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Head;
                firstRequest.RequestUri = new Uri("/files/today.mp4"); //using the same httpClientHandler
                var firstResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(firstRequest);

                //check headers(host, status, Content-Type, Content-Length, etc...)
                //If the content cannot be downloaded, the process ends here.
            }

            {
                var secondRequest = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage();
                secondRequest.Method = System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get;
                secondRequest.RequestUri = new Uri("/files/today.mp4"); //using the same httpClientHandler
                var secondResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(secondRequest);
                var contentData = await secondResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

                //Save contentData to a file
            }

            return new ResponseMessageResult(this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent));
        }
    }


I'd like to express my sincere gratitude to sa-es-ir for his comment.
I have revised the source code based on your advice.
Please rate it!
